# Conditionally centering text in an Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to tell Excel to center the text and keep a numeric value right aligned.  For example in the formula `=IF(+A1=+A2,"Match",+A1-A2)`, I would like Excel to center the word "Match" but right align if there is a numeric value.  I think I used to use the `^` character to center text in Excel but that doesn't appear to work anymore.

Comment: What's with the `+` ?? Why do you use that if you are not adding anything? Excel does not need that. Get rid of old Lotus 123 habits and save thousands of characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set alignment with custom formatting, but you can fake it by setting the cell alignment to center and using this custom format:

```
* #.00; * -#.00;* 0;@
```

It uses the repeat character, `*`, to force numbers to the right. It displays two decimal places, unless the value is zero.